# Question on modular arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Would this ever be possible:

$$a b^2 ≡ a \pmod p$$

where $p$ is a prime number and $1<a<p$ and $1<b$

Please back your answer with some kind of proof other than Fermat's Little Theorem. This isn't homework.

Comment: Put $a=0$ then true for all $b$.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include $p$ and $b$ have to be greater than 1!

Comment: Any $b \equiv \pm 1 \pmod p.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ prime $\rm\: p\ |\ ab^2-a = a\:(b-1)(b+1)\ \Rightarrow\ p\ |\ a\ \ or\ \ p\ |\ b-1\ \ or\ \ p\ |\ b+1$

Comment: I don't see why the answer was downvoted...
Anyways, your answer was perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If $a\equiv0\bmod p$, the given relation is true for all $b$.

If $a\not\equiv0\bmod p$ then $a$ can be cancelled from both sides of the congruence which reduces to $b^2\equiv1\bmod p$, hence $b\equiv\pm1\bmod p$.

Comment: would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: It seems someone is unhappy with both of our answers. I cannot imagine why. But then voting is often irrational here.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p$ is prime, we can cancel $a$ from both sides unless $a\equiv 0 \pmod p$ (this doesn't always work if $p$ is a composite number).  We get $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$.  Again, since $p$ is prime, a number can have only two mod-$p$ square roots (it can have more than two in some cases if $p$ is composite).  The two square roots of $1$ are $\pm 1$ and $-1$ is of course the same as $p-1$.

So $ab^2\equiv a\pmod p$ holds if either $a\equiv 0$ or $b\equiv\pm1$, but not otherwise.

So which parts of this do you want proofs of?  The proof that nonzero numbers are invertible in mod $p$ (thereby justifying the cancelation from both sides)?  I once posted an answer that shows how to find the inverse.  The proof that there can't be more than two square roots if $p$ is prime?  (That latter fact is a sort of corollary.)